# How to let typescript infer the indirect function parameter type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, immer.js

[image]

How can the type of `e` be infered as `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`.

Full Code:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import produce from 'immer';

type RestTuple<T extends [any, ...any[]]> = T extends [any, ...infer R] ? R : never;

function useImmer<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)) {
  const [s, ss] = useState(initialState);
  const immer = useCallback(<F extends (s: S, ...es: any[]) => any>(fn: F) => (...es: RestTuple<Parameters<F>>) =>
    produce(s, s => {
      fn(s as S, ...es);
    }),
    [s]
  );
  return [s, immer, ss] as const;
}

export function MyComponent() {
  const [user, set_user] = useImmer({ name: 'xialvjun', age: 30 });
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={user.name} onChange={set_user((u, e) => (u.name = e.target.value))} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RestTuple` conditional type is preventing the compiler from contextually inferring the callback parameter, as it would require inference to work "backwards" through the definition of `RestTuple`.

Instead, I'd be inclined to make your function generic only in that tuple type `T`, like this:

```
function useImmer<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)) {
    const [s, ss] = useState(initialState);
    const immer = useCallback(<T extends any[]>(fn: (s: S, ...es: T) => void) =>
        (...es: T) =>
            produce(s, s => {
                fn(s as S, ...es);
            }),
        [s]
    );
    return [s, immer, ss] as const;
}
```

Then your call seems to behave better:

```
export function MyComponent() {
    const [user, set_user] = useImmer({ name: 'xialvjun', age: 30 });
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={user.name} onChange={
                set_user((u, e) => (u.name = e.target.value))} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

If you hover in your IDE, you'll see that `e` is now inferred as `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFIDCKANgwEboDWcAvnAGZQQg4AciioMQgNwBYAFChIsOGH4ATfGiS9+goaBBIok2bJ74AdhmAQzBYgEkQ+qAB4SAPgAUwM8BjBGZBRIAFxwJHAAPnAeHgCUcAC8bmGx8TiycJlwaNaE8ADahNiEhAC6ibak5JRePn4B1Uix0jJZ2bnwegYVNPRMrGhsHs4AKnBIAB6UZiqEcChmAJ75pZ48ZqEehKEk2AB0B0jbcCPxSXAAbhDAKmduGW1ZHgd7R6Gnifetjz-KEGoaLbFT64B4-cG8MxbeZzXZwF5HZpgiFcWKYZFtQqlZFI76ZUQwfBQGyFbBdKDFMow9pmPItTjGGSTBTwUwWPzWOAAWUWtAEkDMSDMMDioLxNLycHyNApcGIMAA+jLyglKg4nB48GYUPpQkIJv4GBcAFbmITYFAAcxCcAAzAAGVEtNoEok2DwYrLOFTAC5fFFe7xgfDwGCLMBIBIAIkoUyjl0Y+EjOBle21+m41loAAsFtaEulxQHMvKlcQoDF8NgmiCPPg0zrNKqkHtyFBrTA9hdE01YtwAPT+8HOfs+v04+mMoA)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, Awesome answer.